How can I apply multiple sampling techniques to a single dataset?
Related: How should I split my dataset if I am applying oversampling?
Suppose I have a dataset called my_dataset.dat with three classes. This dataset has a class imbalance, as shown as follows:
LabelColumn
A    459325
C    377954
B    241855

I want to apply both Random Over Sampling and SMOTE to this dataset.
Should I apply those two sampling techniques serially?
I.e.,

Split the dataset into train_data and test_data
Apply random oversampling to the train_data to obtain ros_data
Apply SMOTE to ros_data to obtain ros_smote_data
Use serial_ros_smote_data to train the ML model

Or, should I apply those two sampling techniques parallely?
I.e.,

Split the dataset into train_data and test_data
Apply random oversampling to the train_data to obtain ros_data
Apply SMOTE to train_data to obtain smote_data
Concatenate ros_data and smote_data into palallel_ros_smote_data
Use palallel_ros_smote_data to train the ML model

Note: Authoritative answer needed.

I think this page has the authoritative answer: don’t apply either technique. You don’t even have a 2:1 ratio between the most and least prevalent classes, and with 241855 in the least prevalent class you don’t face the real problem of insufficient data for that class.

It speaks volumes to me that @EdM and I independently referred you to the same discussion about why class imbalance is much less of a problem than many (erroneously) believe.
